# Using Umlaut or special characters in ibm-doors from batch

Tags: ibm-doors

We have a link module that looks something like this:

```cpp
const string  lMod = "/project/_admin/somethingÜ" // Umlaut
```

We later use the linkMod like this to loop through the outlinks:

```cpp
for a in obj->lMod do {}
```

But this only works when executing directly from DOORS and not from a batch script since it for some reason doesn't recognize the Umlaut causing the inside of the loop to never to be run; exchanging `lMod` with `"*"` works and also shows the objects linked to by the `lMod`.

**We are already using UTF-8 encoding for the file:**

```cpp
pragma encoding, "UTF-8"
```

Any solutions are welcome.

Comment: works for me (DOORS 9.7.0.0)... are you sure that you actually saved the dxl file itself in utf-8 encoding?  Check encoding of the file e.g. in Notepad ++.

Comment: @Mike we're still running 9.6, not sure if that makes any difference; I'd have to check the release notes.

Comment: Hey @Mike, apologies. It was saved as ANSI, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the file as `UTF-8` in Notepad++ by going to `Encoding` > `Convert to UTF-8`. (Make sure it's not already set to `UTF-8` before you do it).